# Restangular - $http interceptors

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Morning,

I have a $http interceptor:

```
app.factory('Unauthed', ['$q', 'alertService',function($q,alertService) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            if (response.status == 401) 
                alertService.error('Authentication failure.',15000);

            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
}]);
```

This runs fine for all requests which are going through $http but non which go through Restangular. Looking through the soure Restangular uses $http so I am not sure what is going on here?

Cheers

Comment: this shouldn't happen, but maybe restangular is using .call() or .apply() and it's getting confused between your variable named response, and the method named response?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the order of execution matters, where are you registering restangular? Also maybe order of dependnecies of angular modules, try declaring restangular as dependency of submodules but not in main app module so that $http is already decorated when you add restangular.